# Is there a strictly coassociative resolution of polynomial growth, for a finite group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ a field of characteristic $p$. It is well known, thanks to the work of Quillen, that the trivial $kG$-module $k$ has a projective resolution of polynomial growth. To be more precise, there is a resolution $\cdots \to P_n \to \cdots \to P_1 \to P_0 \to k \to 0$ such that the dimension of $P_n$ is bounded by $Cn^{r-1}$, where $C$ is a positive constant and $r$ is the $p$-rank of $G$, defined as the maximal rank of an elementary abelian $p$-subgroup of $G$.

Given any projective resolution $\mathbf{P}$ as above, by the comparison theorem there is a comultiplication $\Delta\colon \mathbf{P} \to \mathbf{P} \otimes_k \mathbf{P}$, and it induces the multiplication on group cohomology. We say that such a comultiplication is strictly coassociative, if $(1\otimes\Delta)\circ\Delta=(\Delta\otimes 1)\circ\Delta$ as maps from $\mathbf{P}$ to $\mathbf{P}\otimes_k\mathbf{P}\otimes_k\mathbf{P}$.
The minimal resolution usually does not support a strictly coassociative comultiplication. This is related to the lack of formality of the $A_\infty$ structure on group cohomology. The bar resolution is strictly coassociative, but has exponential growth.

My question is this: How small a resolution of $k$ as a $kG$-module exists, that supports a strictly coassociative comultiplication? Is there one of polynomial growth?

If $G$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group, then the minimal resolution in characteristic two supports a strictly coassociative comultiplication. But even for the cyclic group of order $3$ in characteristic $3$, I don't know the answer, despite fiddling around for quite a while with it.

Comment: This question has been in the back of my mind for several years. I was inspired to post it here by seeing Neil Strickland's post on $\Sigma_p$.